# C# EventHandler - No overload matches delegate (huh?)

Tags: c#, event-handling, overloading

`AfterOpenDocument` event works fine, but I cannot get my code to compile when I add the second event `BeforeSaveDocument`.

The error I receive is:

> No overload for `QWApp_BeforeSaveDocument` matches delegate `QuoteWerks.__Application_BeforeSaveDocumentEventHandler`

I'm fairly new to c#, but I think it must be some oversight.

```
  QWApp.AfterOpenDocument  += new __Application_AfterOpenDocumentEventHandler(QWApp_AfterOpenDocument);
  QWApp.BeforeSaveDocument += new __Application_BeforeSaveDocumentEventHandler(QWApp_BeforeSaveDocument);

  void QWApp_AfterOpenDocument()
    {
        string todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        QWApp.DocFunctions.SetDocumentHeaderValue("DocDate", todayDate, false);
        QWApp.DocFunctions.RefreshDisplay();
    }

   public void QWApp_BeforeSaveDocument(int iSaveAction, bool bCancel)
    {
        string todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        QWApp.DocFunctions.SetDocumentHeaderValue("DocDate", todayDate, false);
        QWApp.DocFunctions.RefreshDisplay();
    }
```

Comment: It's hard for us to know what's wrong without knowing about the delegate signature. What does `__Application_BeforeSaveDocumentEventHandler` look like?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, after typing `+=` press `Tab` twice, this will generate a stub method with the appropriate signature.

Comment: What's with the double underscores? *sigh*

Comment: The double underscores I have no idea. I copied this code from a posting in the applications forum.  However when I comment out the using Quotewerks reference, VS says "type or namespace not found", so it must be related to that reference.

Comment: I got it to work. see reply below for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As compiler says, `__Application_BeforeSaveDocumentEventHandler` delegate has different arguments than `QWApp_BeforeSaveDocument`.

Make sure arguments are the same for both.

If I were to guess, you should have `ref bool bCancel` or (less likely, `out bool bCancel`) in `QWApp_BeforeSaveDocument`. Again, check your `__Application_BeforeSaveDocumentEventHandler` delegate, and make your function have the same arguments.

Comment: `ref bool` is more likely IMHO, since you can easily have multiple event handlers chained.

Comment: Super Duper!  I did the {tab} {tab} to generate a stub method with the appropriate signature after entering +=, and sure enough the 'ref' before bool bCancel  (ref bool bCancel) was the missing item.     Can someone explain to me what the ref means?

Comment: It means ["pass by reference"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That means that the parameters to your handler don't match the parameters to the event (delegate).
Check the tooltip for the delegate constructor to find out what parameters it takes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about that library, but on this [page](http://forums.quotewerks.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=669), the signature for the BeforeSaveDocument event is `BeforeSaveDocument (short, ref bool)`

I would try changing iSaveAction to short and/or making the boolean parameter a ref parameter and seeing if that compiles.

Comment: Yup ref was this issue.  Can you explain to me wha the ref parameter means?

Comment: Here is an explanation that will be better than I could do here in 500 characters or less.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx